# Azure Data Factory Copy is always copying 100 rows

Tags: copy, azure-data-factory

I have a Pipeline that was working fine in a Development Environment (tables of 100s or 1000s of rows), but is not working properly in tests in a Production Environment (much larger); on digging, I find the Copy always reports 100 rows (property "rowsCopied"), which is definitely wrong, and is not happening in the Development Environment, which is running an identical Pipeline. This is reflected in the DB data (wrongly) written.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro the issue but it working fine for me even for big files.

I have copied a CSV file with 93487 rows from Blob Storage to Azure SQL Database. It copied without any issue. Check my **Sink** settings below.

[image]

I kept **Write batch size** to 100, means **Number of rows to insert into SQL table per batch.** This will help to copy large data in less time.

Total rows in Sink table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, but I discovered the problem myself; it was in the Dataset definition (i.e. not the Pipeline), and had essentially arisen from an incorrectly edited copy / paste. I understand it better now.